# How can I put some buttons on the bottom of the screen but?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I want to put some buttons on the bottom of the screen , but without using a bar because I would like that the bottons stays above the other widget but stays on the button of the screens ,even if the widget under them is scrollable

[Like the four buttons here in this snapchat screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d5MQc.png)

Comment: Use Stack layout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to use a Stack widget which takes children widgets. You would add the background widget first and then use a Positioned widget to well... position the widget(s) (which in this case are the buttons you want at the bottom of the screen) you want in the foreground where you want.

Check out sample code below:

```
class BottomButtonPosition extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          ListView(children: <Widget>[
            ...List.generate(
              10,
              (index) => Container(
                    color: Colors.primaries.elementAt(index),
                    height: 100.0,
                  ),
            ),
          ]),
          Positioned(
            bottom: 0.0,
            right: 0.0,
            left: 0.0,
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
              children: <Widget>[
                IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(
                    Icons.play_arrow,
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                  iconSize: 40,
                  onPressed: () {},
                ),
                IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(
                    Icons.skip_previous,
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                  iconSize: 40,
                  onPressed: () {},
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Here is the result:

[image]

Comment: OP asks about buttons, your answer doesn't mention buttons, only backgrounds.... ?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I included buttons in the code but I'll edit to specify buttons in the comment.